# Magnitude less than 1 in function transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm currently trying to get myself through Khan Academy, and I am completely loss in function transformation.

Twice I have been essentially guessing at the what to do in terms of these transformation because I can't understand the concept of **maginitude less than 1**. I have no idea what it means, and it is in several exercises without explanation.

Here is a [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/manipulating-functions/) to the section.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z7yp.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmlxH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE $1$: Magnitude Greater than $0$ but Less than $1$

A magnitude less than $1$ means a function with the $a$ term $0<a<1$, where $f(x)=ax^2+bc+c$. This is for quadratic functions.

Take an example of the function $x^2$. To vertically shrink it by a factor of $2$ would mean to multiply the $a$ term by $1/2$.

Therefore, the $a$ term, or the "magnitude", would now be $1/2$, and the function would be $f(x)=1/2x^2$, a function with a magnitude less than $1$ but greater than $0$.

CASE $2$: Magnitude Less than $0$

The function $f(x)=x^2$, if you make the magnitude of the function $-1$, the function would be $f(x)=-x^2$. This means reflecting the original function over the $x$ axis.

Here is a graph which displays $f(x)=x^2$(RED), $g(x)=1/2x^2$(GREEN), and $h(x)=-x^2$ (YELLOW)

[image]

Comment: I am still having problems with that fact that the red seems much smaller than the green. For some reason, I would think that the red would be much larger than the green, but I guess I am missing something.

Comment: Define "larger" and "smaller". @Aaron

Comment: I am talking about the horizontal access where the green has wider area than the red